# Bash store json response in another variable

Tags: json, bash, variables, jq

I'm curling an endpoint:

```
#!/bin/bash
instance_info=$(curl -sk https://internal.admin.com/app/instance)
```

which gives a json response:

```
{
"basePath": "/install", 
"metadata": {
    "deployed_artifact": "app01", 
    "docker": "True",  
    "http_port": "7471",
    "url": "www.google.com"
}, 
"name": "app-01", 
"server": "webserver1"
}
```

I'm trying to avoid curling more than once to get the variables I need from the json using JQ.

Using bash I'd really appreciate if someone can show me how to store the response as another var and then use this to variablize name: server: url: http_port:

The following seems to run the curl twice:

```
#!/bin/bash
instance_info=$(curl -sk https://internal.admin.com/app/instance)

server_name=$(echo instance_info | /usr/bin/jq --raw-output '.server')
url=$(echo instance_info | /usr/bin/jq --raw-output '.url')
```

Comment: No, your example runs curl only once.

Comment: I don't see why the curl line would be executed twice.
How do you tell it is executed twice?

Comment: And you can get rid of the echo using `/usr/bin/jq <args> <<< "$instance_info"`.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `curl` once and this suffices. Then you have the content in a variable, so you can access it without calling `curl` again.

Regarding your code, your approach is fine but you are missing `$` when you are echoing the variable:

```
server_name=$(echo $instance_info | /usr/bin/jq --raw-output '.server')
#                  ^
```

See a sample. Here I hardcode the JSON:

```
your_json='
{
"basePath": "/install", 
"metadata": {
    "deployed_artifact": "app01", 
    "docker": "True",  
    "http_port": "7471",
    "url": "www.google.com"
}, 
"name": "app-01", 
"server": "webserver1"
}'
```

for the `server`:

```
$ echo "$your_json" | jq --raw-output '.server'
webserver1
```

For the `url` you need to indicate the block where it lies on. That is, `metadata`:

```
$ echo "$your_json" | jq --raw-output '.metadata.url'
www.google.com
```

To store into a variable, say:

```
your_field=$(echo "$your_json" | jq --raw-output 'XXXX')
#                                                 ^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script which demonstrates how to use jq's `@sh` formatting directive along with bash `eval` to set bash variables using the output of a filter.  In this case we hardcode the json which presumably would have come from `curl`.

```
#!/bin/bash
instance_info='
{
"basePath": "/install", 
"metadata": {
    "deployed_artifact": "app01", 
    "docker": "True",  
    "http_port": "7471",
    "url": "www.google.com"
}, 
"name": "app-01", 
"server": "webserver1"
}'

eval "$(jq -M -r '@sh "server_name=\(.server) url=\(.metadata.url)"' <<< "$instance_info")"

echo $server_name
echo $url
```

When run this produces the output

```
webserver1
www.google.com
```

The [Extract data and set shell variables](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#extract-data-and-set-shell-variables) section of the [JQ Cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook) has more examples of `@sh`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -rn 's/[ ]*"([^"]*)"[^"]*("[^"]*").*/\1=\2/gp'' file.json
```

O/P:

```
basePath="/install"
deployed_artifact="app01"
docker="True"
http_port="7471"
url="www.google.com"
name="app-01"
server="webserver1"
```

`eval` this output you can get the variable

```
eval $(sed -rn 's/[ ]*"([^"]*)"[^"]*("[^"]*").*/\1=\2/gp' file.json )
echo $name $server
```

O/p:

```
app-01 webserver1
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the values with one `jq` pass then there's no need to store the json:

```
read name server url http_port < <(
    curl -sk https://internal.admin.com/app/instance | \
    jq --raw-output '[.name, .server, .metadata.url, .metadata.http_port] | join(" ")'
)

echo -e "\$name: $name\n\$server: $server\n\$url: $url\n\$http_port $http_port"
$name: app-01
$server: webserver1
$url: www.google.com
$http_port 7471
```